# error with document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, jsp, getelementbyid, scriptlet

I am trying to write a jdo query in which I have to get a set of values based on the category that the user selects on the jsp...my query looks like this

```
Query query2 = pm.newQuery("select from " + ProductDB.class.getName()+ "where pCategory = " document.getElementById("cname").text);
```

Now on my jsp page, I have a dynamic drop-down box and in the  tag I have given the id tag as "cname". So when I execute the above query I am hoping it will get the category that the user selects.

However I am getting this error:

`Syntax error on token "document", delete this token`

My select tag looks like this :

```
<select name = "cname" id="cname">
.
.
.
</select>
```

What am i missing here?

**UPDATE** :

I am putting my entire code for the jsp file below :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.jdo.Query"%>
<%@ page import="javax.jdo.PersistenceManager"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.User"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory"%>
<%@ page import="java.net.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest"%>
<%@ page import="com.nerdy.needs.*"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Product Inventory</title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="450">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<h1 align="center">Product Inventory</h1>
<body>
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>View</td>
        <td><select name="cname" id="cname">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <%
                PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
                Query query = pm.newQuery("select cname from "
                        + CategoryDB.class.getName());
                List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
                categories = (List<String>) query.execute();
                String[] c = categories.toArray(new String[categories.size()]);
                for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                    String s = c[i];
            %>
            <option value="<%=s%>"><%=s%></option>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </select></td>
        <td>Products</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<%
    if (document.getElementById("cname").value == "all") {
        PersistenceManager pm1 = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Query query1 = pm1.newQuery("select * from "
                + ProductDB.class.getName());
        List<ProductDB> prods1 = (List<ProductDB>) query1.execute();
        if (prods1.isEmpty()) {
%>
<table class="items">
    <tr>
        <th class="main">Image</th>
        <th class="main">Category</th>
        <th class="main">Name</th>
        <th class="main">Price</th>
        <th class="main">Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lightBlue">
        <td class="actions" colspan=100%>
        <p>No items were found.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%
    } else {
%>
<table class="topics">
    <tr>
        <th class="main">Image</th>
        <th class="main">Category</th>
        <th class="main">Name</th>
        <th class="main">Price</th>
        <th class="main">Description</th>
    </tr>
    <%
        for (ProductDB p : prods1) {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p><b> <img width="100" height="100"
            src="http://localhost:8888/serve?id= <%=p.getProductImage()%>">
        </b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><b><%=p.getProductCategory()%></b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><b><%=p.getProductName()%></b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><b><%=p.getProductPrice()%></b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><b><%=p.getProductDescription()%></b></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
<%
    pm1.close();
        }
    } else {
        PersistenceManager pm2 = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Query query2 = pm.newQuery("select * from "
                + ProductDB.class.getName() + "where pCategory = "
                + document.getElementById("cname").value);
        List<ProductDB> prods2 = (List<ProductDB>) query2.execute();
        if (prods2.isEmpty()) {
%>
<table class="items">
    <tr>
        <th class="main">Image</th>
        <th class="main">Category</th>
        <th class="main">Name</th>
        <th class="main">Price</th>
        <th class="main">Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="lightBlue">
        <td class="actions" colspan=100%>
        <p>No items were found.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<%
    } else {
%>
<table class="topics">
    <tr>
        <th class="main">Image</th>
        <th class="main">Category</th>
        <th class="main">Name</th>
        <th class="main">Price</th>
        <th class="main">Description</th>
    </tr>
    <%
        for (ProductDB p : prods2) {
    %>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p><b> <img width="100" height="100"
            src="http://localhost:8888/serve?id= %=p.getProductImage()%>">
        </b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><b><%=p.getProductCategory()%></b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><b><%=p.getProductName()%></b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><b><%=p.getProductPrice()%></b></p>
        </td>
        <td>
        <p><b><%=p.getProductDescription()%></b></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
<%
    pm2.close();
        }
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting "document cannot be resolved" errors in two places - one at the if statement

```
if(document.getElementById("cname").value=="all")
```

and the other at the query statement

```
Query query2 = pm.newQuery("select * from " + ProductDB.class.getName()+ "where pCategory = " + document.getElementById("cname").value);
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: @Artyom - what is it that u edited? i cant find the change!

Comment: I added the `jdo` tag :)

Comment: lol..i had put the jdo tag initially but DataNucleus removed the tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concrete problem is that you're mixing Java/JSP with JavaScript. You seem to expect that they run in sync and you seem to expect that JavaScript's `document` object variable is also present in JSP *scriptlet* code.

This is wrong. Java/JSP is a HTML code generator. It runs in webserver upon a HTTP request and generates HTML/JS code and sends it back to webbrowser as HTTP response. All the webbrowser retrieves is plain HTML/JS code. Rightclick the page in webbrowser and do *View Source* to see it yourself.

Your concrete functional requirement seems to be that you need to grab the the submitted value of

```
<select name="cname">
```

in the Java/JSP side.

You need to get it as a request parameter by `HttpServletRequest#getParameter()`. So, replace

```
<%
    if (document.getElementById("cname").value == "all") {
        // ...
    }
%>
```

by

```
<%
    if ("all".equals(request.getParameter("cname"))) {
        // ...
    }
%>
```

That said, writing Java code in JSP files is a [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Work on that as well. Note that this problem is **unrelated** to JDO.

Comment: wow! thanks for the detailed answer...i shall try this method and get back if i have probs. appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the plus mark before the `document.getElementById`.

The correct code would be

```
Query query2 = pm.newQuery("select from " + ProductDB.class.getName() + "where pCategory = " + document.getElementById("cname").text);
```

Also, although that will fix the syntax error, the code still won't work. According to [W3C DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980), the `<select/>` element doesn't have the `text` attribute; you should use the `value`, or `selectedIndex` in conjunction with `options` instead.

Comment: hey ! i tried your method too..as in i put the .value bit the same error persists..any chance something else might be creating this prob ? i tried it with .value and .selectedIndex but no go

Comment: Did you fix the syntax error (the absence of a `+` sign)? What is the exact code you're trying to run now, and what is the exact error message you're receiving?

Comment: yes i fixed the absence of + sign.. thanks for that! my error message now says  
Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Syntax error on token "document", delete 
  this token
 - document cannot be resolved

there are two places where i am using the document.getElementById() method...in that order i am getting these error messages.. do you want me to put the code ?

Comment: <%
if(document.getElementById("cname").value=="all")
{
 PersistenceManager pm1 = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
 Query query1 = pm1.newQuery("select * from " + ProductDB.class.getName());
 List<ProductDB> prods1 = (List<ProductDB>) query1.execute();
this is the place where the first error is showing.. cannot be resolved...

Comment: Query query2 = pm.newQuery("select * from " + ProductDB.class.getName()+ "where pCategory = " + document.getElementById("cname").value);
this is where the second error is showing..delete this token...

Comment: @Shanky: the problem is opening and closing tags **<%** and **%>**

Comment: @Shanky: jsp tags should be declared between tags **<%** and **%>** and other html tags should be outside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:-

```
var i = document.getElementById("cname").selectedIndex;

document.getElementById("cname").options[i].text;
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("cname").value
```

### UPDATE:

Column names are missing too. It should be either `*` or `specific column names`.

```
Query query2 = pm.newQuery("select * from " + ProductDB.class.getName()+ "where pCategory = " + document.getElementById("cname").value);
```

### As per your error update

your code should be as follows:-

```
if(document.getElementById("cname").value=="all") 
{ 
 <%
 PersistenceManager pm1 = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager(); 
 Query query1 = pm1.newQuery("select * from " + ProductDB.class.getName()); 
 List<ProductDB> prods1 = (List<ProductDB>) query1.execute(); 
%>
}
```

JSP tags should be declared between tags **<%** and **%>** and other html tags should be outside.

### As per your Code:

The problem is `document.getElementById("cname").value` calling inside the JSP tags. That is wrong.

Here either you can pass **cname** value as query string and get value through the parameter
OR
Assign `document.getElementById("cname").value` value to JSP variable and process it.

Comment: hi! it still doesnt seem to work :( tried the above methods u mentioned..but not working

Comment: your query is seems not correct. It should be this way **"Query query2 = pm.newQuery("select * from " + ProductDB.class.getName()+ "where pCategory = " + document.getElementById("cname").value); "**

Comment: umm..i dont think we need to put any * in the query coz i ran a similar query elsewhere in my program and it worked fine..i put the errors that i am getting in my comment on the previous answer..check it out..i am thinking there is some import that i need to mention ?? can that be it?

Comment: yes!! there does seem to be probs with my jsp tags...well the error at the if statement is not there anymore..as for the second error in the query line..thats still there..i am new to this site and i dont know how to do that update u did earlier..i would like to put the entire code..i am sure theres some error with the tags..

Comment: @Shanky: At your question, you will see **edit** link. Click on the **edit** link, paste your code at the bottom of your question. If any formattings, we can help you.

Comment: well this is nuts! after putting up the code here..i just tried validating my code in eclipse...the errors are gone! however when i run the jsp file..the same errors at the same lines as i mention appear!